# Is there major performance hit when insert <style> tag dynamically?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, performance, angular7

I'm in an environment where I have to live with AngularJS/Ng7 with majority of the code still stuck in the Ng1 world. Due to various circumstances, I want to temporarily override certain styles **outside** of some angular components. So I came up with a way to dynamically inject an `<style>` tag inside my component which has CSS that override couple level of the parents HTML elements.

Everything is working and I don't observe any page flashing, reload, lag or side effects... but I'm worry that what I can't see doesn't mean there is no impact.

I'd like to know, is there any performance impact and potential side effects that I'm not aware of by injecting a `<style>` tag this way and then removing it along with the component when it gets destroy?

```
  constructor(
    private elRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer2: Renderer2
  ) {
        const style = this.renderer2.createElement('style') as HTMLStyleElement;
    style.innerHTML = `
      #main .helloworld {
        background-color: rebeccapurple !important;
      }
    `;

    (this.elRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement).append(style);
  }
```

The above generates something like this at runtime:

```
<my-component>
  <style>
      #main .helloworld {
        background-color: rebeccapurple !important;
      }
  </style>
  <div>...stuff</div>
</my-component>
```

Comment: `<style>` belongs into the `head-element`. Within the `body` it will be an invalid HTML markup that will not pass any [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) since the deprecation of the `scope` attribute. As such the `style tag` should not be used withing the `body` in the first place.

Comment: I'm not asking whether I can or cannot add a `<style>` within the body. If I live in a perfect world, I'd get rid of Ng1 altogether and fix everything myself. Point is I cannot and I have to deal with the problem.

Comment: well it should because it only works if the browser auto correction does support it. If a browser drops the feature or the suer uses a enw browser that doesnt have this added in the first place, then the style will be messed up as the invalid markup isnt read and as such not applied at all. As such you have an ovios down-side efefct that can occure when injecting a style through the stle tag within the body.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the <style> element isn't being created and appended 100 times per second, there should be no slowdown at all. Especially in modern browsers.